# Why the variable extraDrag not exist in the next line in specific place?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void CalculateDrag()
    {
        float extraDrag = _rigidbody.velocity.magnitude * DragIncreaseFactor;
        _rigidbody.drag = (AirBrakes ? (OriginalDrag*) * AirBreaksEffect : OriginalDrag * extraDrag);
    }
```

DragIncreaseFactor is float.

AirBrakes is bool.

OriginalDrag is float.

The problem is with this part:

(OriginalDrag*)

I want to make: (OriginalDrag * extraDrag) but extraDrag not exist here.
But the extraDrag exist in the end of the line but in this place it's not.

What should i do to fix it to be able to use extraDrag also in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:  `(OriginalDrag*) * AirBreaksEffect`

you are using `*` two times.

As you want to use extra drag in both cases. This is what you should do:

```
_rigidbody.drag = AirBrakes ? OriginalDrag * AirBreaksEffect : OriginalDrag;
_rigidbody.drag *= extraDrag;
```